# Ruby Solr search give less priority for some word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, search-engine, sunspot-solr

I am using Solr search, in which I want to give less priority for some words.
Say if I search for dance lessons, it should get results more results for dance in top and then lessons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sunspot, the answer would be to use [boost](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing#wiki-boost).

[This bit of the docs](http://sunspot.github.io/sunspot/docs/#Phrase_Boosts) shows how to do phrase boosts specifically.

In your case, you may want to give a low number to the boost to effectively reduce the relevance of the word "lesson".

Answer (score 0):

First apology if it doesn't seem to be pointing to the exact code. (I used sunspot long long ago)

So it is possible to boost specific term while you are searching some content. Based on your context I assume the following code should be working -

```
Post.search do
  fulltext 'dance^2 lessons'
end
```

For further term boosting related information you can checkout this page - [Boosting a Term](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term)

Comment: No.but it actually looks for the record with dance^2 lessons and not looking on dance lessons